# convert two different arrays to a dictionary

Tags: python, numpy

I have a numpy array which consists of words and another 2d numpy array which consists a vector corresponding to each word. Is it possible to make a dict using these two arrays so that if I want to replace a word by a vector in another array, I dont have to use numpy.where, which take a hell lot of time?

array of stings = `['the', 'ant', 'basket']` (I have 200k words)
array of vectors corresponding to each sample = `[[2 1 3 4], [1 2 3 7], [5,6,7,8]]`

Comment: Add a sample of the data to the question.

Comment: i have added it now...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
d = dict(zip(array_of_strings, array_of_samples))
```

Or, as @AshwiniChaudhary said, if the arrays are big:

```
from itertools import izip
d = dict(izip(array_of_strings, array_of_samples))
```

Comment: Use `izip` not `zip`.

Answer (score 1):

Use zip:

```
>>> li=['the', 'ant', 'basket'] 
>>> LoL=[[2,1,3,4], [1, 2, 3, 7], [5,6,7,8]]
>>> dict(zip(li,LoL))
{'ant': [1, 2, 3, 7], 'basket': [5, 6, 7, 8], 'the': [2, 1, 3, 4]}
```

or [izip](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip)